# How can I programmatically enter the edit mode in a Tree Control inside a Flex Application

Tags: apache-flex, editmode

I have a Tree Control inside my Flex Application which I want to edit on a doubleclick on a tree item. I found the properties doubleClickEnabled="true", doubleClick="startEditMode()", and editable="true". With these functions I can detect a double click and I can change the editable property to true based on a double click.

The problem is that after I double clicked on a Item i have to click once more to really enter the edit mode. That doesn't seem to be intuitive at all...

Does anybody know the solution on that problem?

Thanks
Markus

Answer (score 1):

Makrus,

Check out the solution posted at:

http://www.sephiroth.it/weblog/archives/2009/12/flex_3_tree_double-click_to_edit.php

Should be just what you are looking for!

-David

Answer (score 0):

A `List` (super class of `Tree`) enters edit mode when the `itemRenderer` is clicked with its `editable` set to `true`. In your case, the `editable` is false, when you click on it - it is set to true only in the `doubleClick` event handler. So this is expected behavior, though not desired in this case.

Try this: Dispatch a `click` with the clicked `itemRenderer` from the `dobleClick` event handler after setting `editable` to `true`.

```
clickedItemRenderer.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
```

I haven't tested this, but I think this might make flex to believe that the item has been clicked again after setting `editable` to true. If this doesn't work, post a working code so that we can tweak with it and try to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

http://tush.wordpress.com/2008/10/06/flex-double-click-to-edit-functionality-for-list-control/

This works like a charm... just tried it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that work for me:

```
        private var ignoreEditing:Boolean = true;
        protected function doubleClickHandler(event: MouseEvent ):void
        {
            ignoreEditing = false;
        }

        protected function itemEditBeginningHandler(event:ListEvent):void
        {
            if(ignoreEditing){
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            else{
                ignoreEditing = true;
            }
        }
```

---

```
<mx:Tree
    doubleClickEnabled="true" 
    editable="true"
    itemEditBegin="itemEditBeginningHandler(event)" 
    doubleClick="doubleClickHandler(event)"
    />
```